# Integral operator is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

If $f\colon \mathbb [0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function, then the function $\int f\colon [0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ defined as $(\int f)(x)=\int_0^x f(y)dy$ is continuous as well. Moreover, this defines a map
$$\mathrm{map}([0,\infty),\mathbb R)\longrightarrow \mathrm{map}([0,\infty),\mathbb R)$$
that is continuous when both mapping spaces are endowed with the compact-open topology.

But the function $\int f$ may be continuous even if $f$ is not continuous. Therefore, one can look, for instance to the space $\mathrm{map}_{\geq}([0,\infty),\mathbb R)$ of lower semi-continuous monotonous functions, and ask whether the function
$$\mathrm{map}_\geq([0,\infty),\mathbb R)\longrightarrow \mathrm{map}([0,\infty),\mathbb R)$$
that sends $f$ to $(\int f)(x):=\int_0^xf(y)dy$ is continuous when the right hand-side space is endowed with the compact-open topology, and the left hand-side space is endowed with the Scott topology. It is not difficult to see that this has an affirmative answer, and I am looking for a reference of this. I also would like to know what happens when the left hand-side is a more general space of discontinuous functions.